# Open up a sql file and running it in PostgreSQL is having an issue with the path because of space in the folder name

Tags: sql, postgresql, cmd

I'm using command line to run the following script:

```
C:\Progra~1\pgAdmin III\1.16\psql -d [tablename] -h [servername] -p 5432 -U postgres -f C:\test\query.sql
```

But the issue comes with the folder `pgAdmin III` that I want to run the query in since it has a space in the name. When I changed the actual folder name to `pgAdminIII` and updated the script it will run the script just fine. I was wondering how I can run this script without physically modifying the folder name (i.e. keep it as pgAdmin III)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put double qoutes around a path with spaces in it:

```
"C:\Progra~1\pgAdmin III\1.16\psql" -d [tablename] ...
```